# Entity frame work code fist relation mapping

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have a database with this schema, is it possible to add list of TimeSlots in both Employee and Clinic? if yes, what is the configuration for its mapping.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No you must have `ClientEmployee` entity which will contain `TimeSlots` navigation property. If you want to have `TimeSlots` in `Employee` and `Clinic` entity you can achieve that only through non-mapped property which will access related `ClientEmployee`:

```
// This is from Employee or Clinic class
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<TimeSlot> TimeSlots
{
    get 
    {
        // ClientEmployees is mapped navigation property
        return ClientEmployees.SelectMany(ce => ce.TimeSlots);
    }
}
```

Do you see the problem? `Employee` and `Clinic` can have multiple related `ClientEmployees` and each `ClientEmployee` can have multiple TimeSlots - this property will give you all time slots for all related `ClientEmployees` - if you want only for one you need a method and pass the `ClientEmployeeId` as parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeSlot> GetTimeSlots(int id)
{
    // ClientEmployees is mapped navigation property
    return ClientEmployees.Where(ce => ce.ClientEmployeeId == id)
                          .Select(ce => ce.TimeSlots);
}
```